# template task: write to root owned directory

Tags: ansible

I want to copy a template generated file to `/etc/init.d` folder. But `template` task doesn't seem to support sudo parameter.
What is the recommended way to handle this? should I copy it to temporary directory and then move file with with sudo?

The playbook task looks like as shown below. Ansible version 1.8.2

```
   - name: copy init script
     template: src=template/optimus_api_service.sh dest=/etc/init.d/optimus-api mode=0755 force=yes owner=root group=root
```

Comment: Can you post your playbook? What version of ansible do you use?

Comment: All tasks support `sudo`. I use it with `template` myself in many cases. I doubt it is the reason but you could update Ansible to the recent version (1.9.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following playbook and it works.

## My setup:

The User `vagrant` on the machine `vm` is allowed to execute commands password-free with `sudo`.

I created a simple template and installed it with the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Test template
  hosts: vm
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: vagrant

  vars:
    bla: blub                # some variable used in the template

  tasks:
    - name:  copy init script
      sudo: yes              # << you have to activate sudo
      sudo_user: root        # << and provide the user
      template: src=template/test.j2 dest=/opt/test mode=0755 force=yes owner=root group=root
```

Comment: is /opt/test owned by root?

Comment: @mig-foxbat: yes it is